# Subclass a Delegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, design-patterns, delegates

I have a class called `ToolbarView` which is a subclass of `UIView` and basically creates a `UIView` that has a disappearing / reappearing `UIToolbar` on top. I also have a subclass of `ToolbarView` called `DraggableToolbarView` which enables the user to drag the view around the screen.

I need to create a delegate for `ToolbarView` so it can notify another object / class of when the toolbar reappears and disappears. I also need to create a delegate for `DraggableToolbarView` so I can notify another object / class when the view is dragged.

Currently, I have create a separate delegate for each, but I am wondering if there is a better pattern for this? Maybe implement one delegate for `ToolbarView`, and list the delegate methods from `DraggableToolbarView` as optional? Or is there a way to subclass a delegate?

What is the best / cleanest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a protocol for your delegate methods (always a good idea anyway), you can have another protocol adopt the first. That sets up an inheritance-like relationship:

```
@protocol ToolbarViewDelegate
// some methods
@end

@protocol DraggableToolbarViewDelegate <ToolBarViewDelegate>
// additional methods
@end
```

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Not at all, actually. It does happen, from time to time, that two people will provide similar answers at about the same time, particularly when there's a canonical answer. Frankly, I think mine is a slightly better answer given that the names of the protocols are more appropriate.

Comment: And it uses the correct term for the relationship between the protocols.

Comment: @Caleb - I've tried implementing in this fashion but I'm not getting it to work. I've listed most of my code in another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768884/trying-to-implement-delegate-inheritance) any chance you might be able to take a look?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can have `inheriting` protocols:

```
@protocol Proto1 

@reqired
-(void) somethingHappened:(id) sender;

@optional
-(void) somethingElseHappened:(id) sender;

@end

@protocol Proto2<Proto1>

// this now contains all of the method signatures found in proto1, with the addition of new ones!

-(void) somethingSpecialHappened:(id) sender;

@end
```

Comment: Do they have to be in the same file? I've tried this for a DraggableToolbarView and it's not implementing the ToolbarView methods.

Comment: @CoDEFRo it doesn't automatically implement the protocols, it simply broadcasts that they are there. You must still add implementations for each.

Comment: +1 just because I think you should at least have the same points as @Caleb's answer, since both answers are pretty much identical

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it right.

Consider `UITextView` which is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.  Each has its own delegate protocol that's responsible for reacting to a specific set of messages.  As long as you think of visibility and dragging as separate concerns, allowing different objects to handle their delegation seems logical.